# XAML The video insert didn't display

Tags: c#, xaml

This is my first time programing in xaml and I'm trying to insert a video in a code behind but didn't display the display go black. I know you guys can help me thank you all for the help.

This is my xaml.cs code.

```
namespace App_Videos_Test
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        PlayVideo(); 

    }

    private async void PlayVideo()
    {
        string VideoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rJwYN_SmOU";
        var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(VideoUrl, YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
        var YoutubePlayer = new MediaElement();
        YoutubePlayer.Source = url.Uri;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
 }
```

And this is my xaml code.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdVideo" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <MediaElement  x:Name="meTestVideo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="578" Margin="188,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code behind you are creating a new `MediaElement` component, and getting that to play your video.

Presumably what you really want to do is play the video on the `MediaElement` you've already created in the XAML - the one called meTestVideo.
In your `PlayVideo()` method you want to reference your existing MediaElement, something like this:

```
private async void PlayVideo()
    {
        string VideoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rJwYN_SmOU";
        var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(VideoUrl, YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
        meTestVideo.Source = url.Uri;
    }
```

Comment: I receive this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I supposed to create a Object right/

Comment: Debug it ... which object is null? You are creating an object of type MediaElement in the XAML, so check whether it is actually that object that is causing the error. What is the `YouTube` object you are performing the method `GetVideoUriAsync` on? Is that a static method, or are you supposed to instantiate a `YouTube` object? Sorry I don't use code behind much, and have never used the MediaElement component, but your fundamental problem was that you were creating two MediaElements - one in code behind and one in xaml - and playing the video on the one in code behind.

Comment: The video comes from youtube site, its supposed when you run de app the video start.

Comment: The var url is comming null.

Comment: I am guessing you are using the YouTube class in the MyToolKit on CodePlex? http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/. As is good practice, you always want to capture possible nulls, and on that site http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Documentation he shows that exact scenario of URL being null. As to why it is null, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mashton. Another thing, not a real answer to your question, but a tips. When working with `MediaElement`, especially in development phase, always handle [MediaFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

With that you'll get notified when an error related to loading media file occur, and you can see informative error message instead of just looking at blank MediaElement control and wondering what is happening. Because `MediaElement` doesn't throw exception in that case, but raise `MediaFailed` event instead.

```
meTestVideo.MediaFailed += meTestVideo_MediaFailed;
void meTestVideo_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Media failed : {0}", e.ErrorException.InnerException));
}
```