# XAML Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

The error is occurred in: meTestVideo.Source = url.Uri; I think I forgot something. I supposed to create a Object? Sorry for my ignorance guys this is my first time programing in xaml.

```
public string Uri { get; set; } 

private async void PlayVideo()
{
        string VideoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rJwYN_SmOU";
        var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(VideoUrl, YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
        meTestVideo.Source = url.Uri;
}
```

Comment: put breakpoint in this line : `meTestVideo.Source = url.Uri;`, and see which one is null, `meTestVideo` or `url`. In case you defined `meTestVideo` in XAML (as shown in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935307/xaml-the-video-insert-didnt-display)), the latter is more likely to be `null`

Comment: @har07 url is coming null.

Comment: we've narrowed the problem down, and the culprit is line of code that responsible to fill `url`, which is `await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(...)`. Unfortunately, that isn't .NET built-in functions, and we don't know what is it.

Comment: what is that youtube library you are using? link to the library website would be helpful.

Comment: Im using this library: 

using MyToolkit;
using MyToolkit.Multimedia;

Comment: so thats the difference between parallels and meridians...! =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use YouTube Video Id in the parameter.

```
public string Uri { get; set; } 

    private async void PlayVideo()
    {
            string VideoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rJwYN_SmOU";
            var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("2rJwYN_SmOU", YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
            meTestVideo.Source = url.Uri;
    }
```